# How to update hour if the minute is more than or equal to 56

Tags: javascript, firebase

The data tree:

```
place:
 bpg: 0
 bpu: 0
 hour: 9
 kia: 0
 minute: 0
 name: "Puskesmas Kecamatan Kelapa Gading"
```

The rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "puskesmas": {
      "faskes": {
        "place": {
          "hour": {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() <= 15"
          },
          "minute": {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() <= 56"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code that I'm currently using:

```
minute.transaction(function(currentRank){
  currentData = Number(currentRank) + Number(dipper);
  return currentData;
})
```

I can't figure out how to write the hour code

The Logic:

The place started from 9 AM to 15 PM, the hour will update from 9 to 10 if minute is more than or equal to 56.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Can you post your code? Rules validate the data is valid - they don't modify it. In this case the rules that you've defined is validating that the hour is less than or equal to 15 and the minute is less than or equal of 56. And why 56? Hour would generally be incremented if minute is > 59.

Comment: The system is about consultation, there's also consultation duration option, it starts from 5 to 10. Technically, if 55 + 5 = 00, and 56 + 5 = 61. That's why I use 56 rather than 59.

Comment: I was asking about the code bruhh

Answer (score 0):

Firebase security rules can validate your data (e.g. "the minute value must be between 0 and 59") and it can ensure that the user performing the action is authorized for that action. But they cannot change the data that is being written.